# jQuery Contact Form Titles Moving Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working to create a contact us form like below.
Demo :https://www.teamwork.com/signup
I want to do is, When I type of text on text box, Textbox Title move to top.
How can I do it. I have write some code in Fiddle.
Can you help me to get this work?
Fiddle :  https://jsfiddle.net/3s9ehc0c/

HTML

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group inner-addon left-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-user-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <input class="form-control user border-style" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="form-group inner-addon left-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-user-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <input class="form-control user border-style" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.border-style {
    border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 17px;
    border-color: #e6e6e6;
    padding-left: 45px;
    background-color: transparent!important;
    background-position: left center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 40px 40px;
    font-family: inherit;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.border-style:focus {
    box-shadow: none;

}

.form-group2 input:focus+i {
    color: blue;
}
.form-group1,
.form-group2 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.form-group1 i,
.form-group2 i {
    order: 1;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
}
.form-group input:focus+i {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Use materilize CSS framework to do that easily they provide the same forum

Comment: Use this easy and perfect https://codepen.io/sevilayha/pen/IdGKH?q=Material+design&limit=all&type=type-pens

Comment: @Ashishsah A library is not necessary to achieve requirement.

Comment: Thank you very much.It works fine. But i want to keep text box underline when data is there. Any idea? @Ashish sah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<i>` element should be placed after the `<input>` element for selector `input:focus+i` to match `<i>` element at HTML.

You can use CSS `:before` pseudo element, `attr()` function to reference `data-*` attribute at HTML, `animation` and `transition` for effect.

```css
.border-style {
  border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-color: #e6e6e6;
  padding-left: 45px;
  background-color: transparent!important;
  background-position: left center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  font-family: inherit;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.border-style:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.form-group2 input:focus+i {
  color: blue;
}

.form-group1,
.form-group2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.form-group1 i,
.form-group2 i {
  order: 1;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
}

.form-group input:focus+i {
  color: blue;
}

.form-group input:focus+i {
  color: blue;
}

.form-group input:focus+i:before {
  content: attr(data-placeholder); /* set content */
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
  left: -214px;
  top: 0px;
  transition: all 1s ease; /* set transition */
  animation: placeholder 1s forwards ease; /* set animation */
}

/* do animation stuff at i element */
@keyframes placeholder {
  to {
    top: -12px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    left: -204px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <form role="form">
      <div class="form-group inner-addon left-addon">
        <input class="form-control user border-style" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
        <i class="fa fa-user-o" aria-hidden="true" data-placeholder="Username"></i>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="form-group inner-addon left-addon">
        <input class="form-control user border-style" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
        <i class="fa fa-user-o" aria-hidden="true" data-placeholder="Username"></i>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.It works fine. But i want to keep text box underline when data is there. Any idea?

Comment: @sanbg Include `.border-style:focus {
  border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
  outline: none;
}` at CSS

Comment: Thanks for your help.