# Auto expanding a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to add an animation to a textarea element?

I came across this snippet I would like to use:
http://jsfiddle.net/n9uuv0hd/104/

```
<textarea placeholder="Type, paste, cut text here..."></textarea>
```

and then looked around for some animation and found this:
https://codepen.io/kpourdeilami/pen/KDepk

how can I apply the same animation to the jsfiddle version?
Is this possible?

Comment: See [jQuery Contact Form Titles Moving Effect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46398104/)

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/n9uuv0hd/111/ there are prettier ways to do this. but it works.